# Get Sorce Code From n-th line

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to get the source code dynamically? Something like this:

Dummy code:

```
 1 int x = 5;
 2 string y = "";
 3 string codeFromLine1 = SomeClass.SomeMethod("currentfilename", 1)
```

codeFromLine1 <===> "int x = 5;"

Comment: Dynamically from where? From the compiled code? You'd need to know where the original file is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# compiles to IL; the app that you ship *almost certainly* won't included the source code in any way, and while IL *can* be reversed back to C# (with the right tools, assuming it hasn't been deliberately obfuscated), it won't always be *the same* at the original source and the line numbers won't be meaningful *at all*. So in general: no. In some very very specific cases: possibly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the original code file

```
int lineNo = 1;
string codeLine = File.ReadLines(fileNameOfSourceCode)
    .Skip(lineNo - 1);
    .First();
```

This might be of some use for a design time tool; however, I don't see what its usage might be at runtime. Note that exceptions yield file names, line numbers and column numbers, if you compile your code in Debug configuration and include the *.PDB file. I might work with the Release configuration as well; however, the code optimizer can confuse things a bit.

Comment: "However, at runtime you don't know which line of code is running." note: `[CallerFilePath]` and `[CallerLineNumber]` do make it possible to embed that info into your app - I'm not saying it is a good thing to do, though! Example: `static (string file, int line) WhoAmI([CallerFilePath] string file = null, [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0) => (file, line);`